# Why Google Chrome is not able to switch between different Favicons on the same website?

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, favicon, razor-pages

I have a ASP.Net application, and in my Layout.cshtm based on a condition I'm trying to change Favicon so different users have different Favicons based on that condition. Here's the snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    bool someCondition = UserInfo.IsCondition;
}
<html lang="@ISO.Substring(0, 2)" data-full-culture="@ISO">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    @if (someCondition == true) { 
            <title ng-bind="'title 1'"></title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/custom-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="icon" href="/custom-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 
        }
    else {
            <title ng-bind="'title 2'"></title>
            // Chrome sets favicon.ico as default, so no need to set it here
        }
</head>
</html>
```

Both favicon.ico and custom-favicon.ico are in my root directory of my project.
Although my title gets changed based on the condition, but the Favicon is set to favicon.ico and won't get updated even though I'm forcing it to change.

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: No problem on other browsers!

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are quite lazy regarding favicon. In your particular case it should be a good thing to gently push them :) Be explicit:

```
@if (someCondition == true) { 
    <title ng-bind="'title 1'"></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/custom-favicon.ico">
}
else {
    <title ng-bind="'title 2'"></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
}
```

If that still don't work, you can:

- Add a timestamp at the end of the icon URLs, to make browsers consider them as new files every time (eg. `/favicon.ico?v=@timestamp`).
- Use JS to set favicon explicitly, yet this is a bit overkill. For example, see [faviconjs](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/).

PS: You probably don't need the duplicated `shortcut icon` / `icon` declarations. But forcing the browser to regularly switch icons might change this. Please let me know.

Comment: Explicitly forcing it didn't work; Nor adding timestamp to the end of icon URL. I ended up using JS to set favicon when the condition is True.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Good to know!